# How do I :let a global variable in my vimrc in vim9script?

Tags: vimrc, vim9script, vim9

I am trying to change my `vimrc` to `vim9script`. For inbuilt fortran help, (`:h fortran`)
we have:

```
:let fortran_free_source=1
```

This is giving an error:

```
E1126: Cannot use :let in Vim9 script
```

If I remove the let, I am getting:

```
E492: Not an editor command:    fortran_free_source = 1
```

How should I update this?

Comment: Your question has no accepted answer. Is there an aspect of the question that has not been addressed? Otherwise maybe could you accept the response using the v green button. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you have to declare the variable once using `var`

```
vim9script

var fortran_free_source = 1
```

is the equivalent of:

```
let s:fortran_free_source=1
```

After the variable has been declared you can modify it without using `let`.

```
vim9script

var fortran_free_source = 1

# I change my mind:
fortran_free_source = 0
```

But if you want to change a global variable they need not to be declared hence:

```
vim9script

# Set a global variable:
g:fortran_free_source = 1
```

is the equivalent of:

```
" Set a global variable:
let g:fortran_free_source=1
```

Comment: I think in this case it should just be: `g:fortran_free_source = 1`. Globals are not declared with "var" and the spaces around the equal sign are required.

Comment: Thanks @Heptite :-) I have adapted the solution accordingly.

Comment: I would reword: "is equivalent of:" -- it is not. It would be the same as `let s:fortran_free_source`

Comment: Thanks @Maxim, I was hesitating since if you are in a function I suppose `x = 1` is equivalent to `let a:x`, `let v:x = 1`  or `let s:x` depending if `x` is a function argument n local variable or a script variable.

Comment: `let somevar = 1` in a function would be `let l:somevar`, in a script `let s:somevar` (provided there were no global var with the same name defined beforehand)